# Dynamically define a super method for an instance of a class in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Say we have a class that we cannot change,

```rb
class C
  def foo
    super
    puts "Low!"
  end
end
```

We'll need to dynamically define the method `foo` in something that we'll be able to inject into C's ancestry chain. The behavior of `super` must be specific to a given object, not class-wide. We'll be able to enclose that logic into an anonymous module (let's name it for now):

```rb
module M
  def foo
    puts "High!"
  end
end
```

Extending an instance of `C` with the module:

```rb
c = C.new
c.extend(M)
c.foo
# High!
```

will not work since we've put the method from the module before the method we've defined in the class. Looking at our object's ancestors

```rb
c.singleton_class.ancestors
# => [#<Class:#<C:0x00005652be630b20>>, M, C, ...]
```

I came up with an ugly workaround, which is redefining the methods from our class in our singleton_class, i.e.

```rb
c.define_singleton_method(:foo, c.class.instance_method(:foo))
c.foo
# High!
# Low!
```

While this works (does it work? I've tested it for a bit and it seems to, but I'm no longer certain), I wonder whether I'm missing something obvious and there's an easier way to dynamically define a "super" method for an instance of a class.

To be clear, we want to be able to extend another instance of `C` with another module, i.e.

```rb
C.new.extend(Module.new do
  def foo
    puts "Medium!"
  end
end).foo
# Medium!
# Low!
```

and have its output not tainted by other instances.

Comment: I don't think there is a good way to do this.  I'd suggest that you should not be using `super` like this and instead just call a method that has some meaningful name.  Alternatively, you could make the object hold an array of Proc objects in instance variable if you need things to be more flexible.  `@procs.each { |proc| proc.call }`

Comment: @DavidGrayson I'm aware of how hackish this is. The example is simplified, in reality there is a discontinued gem I'm trying to work around. This wouldn't be my go-to-solution but I still thought it was a fun standalone question within the realm of possibility in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understand you're trying to work around an issue in some third-party code, I can suggest a more reasonable solution.  In the code below, I'm thinking that `B` and `C` are defined by the gem and you don't want to change their source code, but you want to inject some code into the place where `C#foo` calls `B#foo`.

```rb
class B
  def foo
    puts "Highest!"
  end
end

class C < B
  def foo
    super
    puts "Low!"
  end
end

module CE
  def foo
    super
    foo_injected
  end
end

C.include(CE)

module M
  def foo_injected
    puts "High!"
  end
end

c = C.new
c.extend(M)
p c.singleton_class.ancestors
c.foo
```

The output is:

```
[#<Class:#<C:0x000055ce443366a8>>, M, C, CE, B, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
Highest!
High!
Low!
```